# Populating an Excel File Using an API to track Card Prices in Python

Tags: python, excel, api

I'm a novice when it comes to Python and in order to learn it, I was working on a side project. My goal is to track card prices of my YGO cards using the yu-gi-oh prices API https://yugiohprices.docs.apiary.io/#

I am attempting to manually enter the print tag for each card and then have the API pull the data and populate the spreadsheet, such as the name of the card and its trait, in addition to the price data. So anytime I run the code, it is updated.

My idea was to use a for loop to get the API to search up each print tag and store the information in an empty dictionary and then post the results onto the excel file. I added an example of the spreadsheet.

Please let me know if I can clarify further. Any suggestions to the code that would help me achieve the goal for this project would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
import requests
import response as rsp
import urllib3
import urlopen
import json
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("api_ygo.xlsx")
print(df[:5])  # See the first 5 columns

response = requests.get('http://yugiohprices.com/api/price_for_print_tag/print_tag')
print(response.json())

data = []
for i in df:
    print_tag = i[2]
    request = requests.get('http://yugiohprices.com/api/price_for_print_tag/print_tag' + print_tag)
    data.append(print_tag)

print(data)

def jprint(obj):
    text = json.dumps(obj, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
    print(text)

jprint(response.json())
```

[Example Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqJoY.png)

Comment: What exactly is the question? What's the problem with your code?

Comment: Hi sorry, about the misunderstanding, how would I be able to use a for loop so that it populates my example spreadsheet. Right now it only returns one response where it is looping over just "print_tag" and not the whole column

Comment: Ok, that clarifies it, I've posted a solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over a `pandas` dataframe can be done using [df.apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html). This has the added advantage that you can store the results directly in your dataframe.
First define a function that returns the desired result. Then apply the relevant column to that function while assigning the output to a new column:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import time

df = pd.DataFrame(['EP1-EN002', 'LED6-EN007', 'DRL2-EN041'], columns=['print_tag']) #just dummy data, in your case this is pd.read_excel

def get_tag(print_tag):
    request = requests.get('http://yugiohprices.com/api/price_for_print_tag/' + print_tag) #this url works, the one in your code wasn't correct
    time.sleep(1) #sleep for a second to prevent sending too many API calls per minute
    return request.json()

df['result'] = df['print_tag'].apply(get_tag)
```

You can now export this column to a list of dictionaries with `df['result'].tolist()`. Or even better, you can flatten the results into a new dataframe with [pd.json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```
df2 = pd.json_normalize(df['result'])
df2.to_excel('output.xlsx') # save dataframe as new excel file
```

Comment: You're passing the filename as a list,but it should be a string. Try this: `df = pd.read_excel('api_ygo.xlsx')`

Comment: Try this: `request = requests.get('http://yugiohprices.com/api/price_for_print_tag/' + str(print_tag))`. But try to trace the debugging issue yourself. I can only guess since I don't have the data or full debugging code. Apparently it is passing a float to the function. Are all print tags in the excel file correct?